# How to Change the Default text "The survey is empty.." to something else?

Tags: surveyjs

The survey js creator editor show "Change Servey editor text "The survey is empty. Drag an element from the toolbox or click the button below." to "Add here" as default text, I want to Change it to "Click on Add Question Button to Start creating your survey." How I can do that?

[image]

I tried setting different properties but not worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change this text by modifying the [ed.surveyPlaceHolder](https://github.com/surveyjs/survey-creator/blob/master/packages/survey-creator-core/src/localization/english.ts#L145) localization string. For more information on how to override individual translations, refer to https://surveyjs.io/survey-creator/documentation/localization#override-individual-translations.